# Stop hook_entity_access early?

Tags: entities

We're leveraging [Permissions By Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term) to limit access to various content. We are hitting some performance issues, though, so I'm attempting to add a patch that allows/denies access to nodes given certain conditions. PBT implements its access controls via hook_entity_access.

However, when a user hits a node and I allow/deny access to it, hook_entity_access continues to run its checks for every other entity present on the page (which is bad because that's what's causing the performance issues in the first place). Is there a way to choke `hook_entity_access()` and just accept access for the first page and skip everything else?

Comment: It depends on how you're adding additional entities to the page. Can you provide more context?

Comment: I believe that most of them are coming from paragraphs and entity reference fields. In one instance, a view block is pulled in through a paragraph and the access check was run on every node in the view listing.